# How to install the OR-Tools C++ binary distribution in Visual Studio 2022 (Win10)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, or-tools

Windows 10 21H2 19044.1645
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.7.6
or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996

I have been using the python version of or-tools before, and now I want to try the c++ version. But I tried for two days and search a lot of information on the Internet, but I still couldn't get the program to run. I don’t know which one I did wrong or what steps I missed. I hope you can help me figure it out.

**Details are as follows:**

I download the binary distribution: [or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996.zip](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/download/v9.7/or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996.zip) and extracted it to the directory: "E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Libs\or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996".

I create a new `Empty Project (C++)` and name it "TestProject" in Visual Studio, and the project will be created in "E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Project\TestProject\".

I `Add > New Item` and name it "program.cc" as file name in the project, and I copy and paste the code which is in [Get Started with OR-Tools for C++](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp) into the "program.cc" file.

I right-clicked the project to open `Properties` and modified the following settings for both `Configuration: Release` and `Configuration: Debug`:
Set `Configuration Properties > General > C++ Language Standard` to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`.
Set `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library` to `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`.
Add `E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Libs\or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996\include` into `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`.
Add `E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Libs\or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2022_cpp_v9.7.2996\lib` into `Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`.
Add `ortools_full.lib` into `Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`.

I select `Solution Configurations` as `Release`, and I select `Solution Platforms` as `x64`, and I press `▶ Local Windows Debugger` so the program starts running.

And I get 7 Errors, 200 Warnings, 0Messages.

**Error List:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Please help me, thank you.

Crossposted at https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using or-tools in Visual Studio.

I found this thread: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3888

It looks like utf8_validity.cc is missing from the build. A quick fix described in the above link is to add https://github.com/protocolbuffers/utf8_range/blob/main/utf8_validity.cc to your project. This fixes the linking error in my project, and the code is running now. Perhaps worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, or-tools is built against `/std:c++20` since code use some aggregate initialization...

ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

note: This has been silently enabled in gcc/clang in `-std=c++17` so unix like OS (linux, macOS) are compiled against C++17...

note2: "designator expression" is supported since C99.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by accepted answer,
Add utf8_validity.lib into Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.
Fixed my problem.